# Alignment Of Cells ar not the same

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in FormLoad event -

```
DataGridView1.Columns("Note").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
```

I want this column only with alignment MiddleLeft....
As you can see, only the first row is OK. What should I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the `DataGridView.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment` property is set to the default value `NotSet`. The same for the `DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment` property.
2. Set the `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment` property to `MiddleCenter` value to have the cell contents aligned at the middle center except,
3. By code or grid designer, set the `Note` column `.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment` property to `MiddleLeft`.

In other words, in the Form's ctor or `Load` event and before populating the grid:

```vb
DataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet
DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet
DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
DataGridView1.Columns("Note").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
```

**Further Reading**

[Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)